# Visio VBA public array redim fails

Tags: vba, visio

I have a userform that processes some data and saves it to an array. I would like to make this array available to use the NEXT TIME I open the userform. So far I have tried: static variables, global variables, and SaveSettings but nothing has worked. Here is my current attempt:

In the ThisDocument module:

`Public cache ' as a global, this is outside of any sub/function`

In the Userform module:

```
Private Function PopulateList(pat As String)
    
    ThisDocument.cache = Array()
    Dim retArr
    retArr = Array()
    Dim regEx As Object
    Set regEx = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
    Dim matchedRows As Integer
    matchedRows = 0
    
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .pattern = pat
    End With

    Dim lngRowIDs() As Long
    Dim vsoRecordSet As DataRecordset
    Dim rowMatches As Boolean
    Set vsoDataRecordset = Visio.ActiveDocument.DataRecordsets(0)
    lngRowIDs = vsoDataRecordset.GetDataRowIDs("")
    
    For lngRow = LBound(lngRowIDs) To UBound(lngRowIDs) + 1
        rowMatches = False
        varRowData = vsoDataRecordset.GetRowData(lngRow)
        If regEx.Test(CStr(varRowData(0))) Then
            rowMatches = True
        End If
    
        ' THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART BELOW HERE
        If rowMatches Then
            ReDim Preserve retArr(matchedRows)
            retArr(matchedRows) = Array(CStr(varRowData(0)), CStr(varRowData(1)), varRowData(2), varRowData(3))
            ReDim Preserve ThisDocument.cache(matchedRows)
            ThisDocument.cache(matchedRows) = Array(CStr(varRowData(0)), CStr(varRowData(1)), varRowData(2), varRowData(3))
            matchedRows = matchedRows + 1
        End If
    Next lngRow
    
    PopulateList = retArr
    
End Function
```

Below the THIS IS THE IMPORTANT PART comment you can see I am trying to set the cache array to be the same as the retArr. When calling ReDim, retArr works as expected but the same operation for ThisDocument.cache fails to compile with a `data member not found` error. Why is this?

Comment: I recommend you use a collection and never ReDim an array ever again. 
https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-collections/

Answer (score 0):

`ThisDocument` is not a module, it is an object. In your code, the compiler probably  simply does not see it (does not understand what `ThisDocument` is). That is why you get the compilation error (redim is applicable to arrays only)

Maybe it is a conceptual problem. Do you expect your global vba variable values to be saved in the document between runs?